# How do I loop and stop a sound using the same button in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 4 buttons on stage and I need a code that enables me to click on one of them, loop a specific sound "infinitely", and when it is clicked again, the sound stops. The sound is not initially playing. Also, while one of the sounds is looping, if I press another button, I'd like the previous sound to stop and the new one to play.

To help visualize this more, I will explain my project. I have to create an 'app' that is like an online guitar tuner. This feature is sort of what I would like to recreate:

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/tuner/

I don't even know where to begin with the coding... any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Make an attempt yourself... Post the specific problem when you get stuck somewhere. For starters... try the refrence: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

Answer (score 0):

The actual code is quite dependent on how you are loading in the sound, so I will write the "skeleton" for the code.

```
var currentSound:Sound = null;
var currentSoundChannel:SoundChannel;

var sound1:Sound = /* Load me */
var sound2:Sound = /* Load me */


button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound1);
function playSound1(event:MouseEvent)
{
    playSound(sound1);
}

button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound2);
function playSound2(event:MouseEvent)
{
    playSound(sound2);
}


function playSound(sound:Sound):void
{
    if (currentSound != null)
    {
        // Stop the current music
        currentSoundChannel.stop();
    }

    if (currentSound == sound)
    {
        // Stop playing ANY sound
        currentSound = null;
        currentSoundChannel = null;
    }
    else
    {
        // Play a different sound
        currentSound = sound;
        currentSoundChannel = sound.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the repetitious code for the buttons and their listeners, but if you are a beginner, it may be easier writing things out like I have in the example.